# Synchronize git-svn branch with git repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

We have a client that has SVN as version control. We have to work with their repository and they don't want to create branches for us, only the branch they deploy, so we cannot create small commits, only a big one when the feature is ready to be deployed.

I've read about git-svn and I think it's almost the perfect solution. But is there a way of synchronizing locally created branches with an external repository? Both to backup and sync with other people.

I mean, you have the SVN repository. Clone it with Git and create a branch (locally, not allowed to do in the SVN repo). Is there a way of making that branch point to any newly created repository. Like a different repository created from that branch.

I hope I could explain it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have cloned the subversion repository with something like this

```
git svn clone -s $SVN_URL proj-clone
```

you can add a "real" git remote repository:

```
cd proj-clone
git remote add team $GIT_URL
```

You have to choose a different remote name than the usual `origin` because `git svn` would use the same refs (e.g. `refs/remotes/origin/trunk`) for tracking as `git remote`.

After that you can pull/push as usual to the git-remote.

---

If - on the other hand - you only want to track *one* branch like this:

```
git svn clone $SVN_URL/trunk proj-clone
```

then `git svn`  dos not use the namespace `refs/remotes/origin/*` but `refs/remotes/git-svn`. In this case you can use the usual `origin`as the remote name.

---

In any case: You can modify this by using the `--prefix=` parameter during `git svn clone`. (See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn---prefixltprefixgt)).