# Git svn difference between directories .git/logs/refs/... and .git/refs/

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

I'm doing a migration from **svn** to **git** with **git svn** command.

After the command does its job I, have two simmilar directories:

- `*.git/logs/refs/remote/origin*` and
- `*.git/refs/remote/origin.*`

My question is what is the difference between them?
Because in the `*.git/refs/remote/origin*` I'm missing the `trunk` branch which is visible in `*.git/logs/refs/remote/origin*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Git repository layout](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout) page is the reference for that:

- [`.git/logs/refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout#Documentation/gitrepository-layout.txt-logs) records of changes made to refs are stored in this directory.
  Use by [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)
- [`.git/refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout#Documentation/gitrepository-layout.txt-refs) lists references stored in subdirectories of this directory.

So this is not linked specifically to [`git svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

It then depends on the exact `git svn` command used.
As shown in "[Synchronize git-svn branch with git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53979632/6309)", a `git svn clone $SVN_URL/trunk proj-clone` would mean that  `git svn` does not use the namespace `refs/remotes/origin/*` but `refs/remotes/git-svn`.

Comment: Ok, now I undestand the logic of logs. The next part is about the command and it's result. The full used command is: *git svn clone $svn_url -A authors.csv --no-metadata --tags=/tags --branches=/branches --trunk=/trunk --log-window-size=500 -s git-svn-project*. Now as I sad the trunk in this project is avaliable, but not after the command it the dir .git/refs/remotes/origin.

Comment: @gregorvojvoda I am not familiar with `git svn`, but `-s` suggests "standard layout". Maybe in that case `trunk` is mapped to `master`?